# print lines between lines started with special character in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have a text file which is like:

```
 #aabc
 ld
 #ac
 bc
 acz
 c
 #hello
```

I want to read this file and check the lines between lines started with "#". If the line is started with "#" then ignore it and if it is not started with "#" then redirect the whole line in another file.
thus the content of the file (new) should be at first attempt:

```
ld
```

I want to modify question a bit.

Question is like that,
a) first of all read the file till second occurrence of "#" i.e. till "#ac" in above. Now you have lines:

```
 #aabc
 ld
 #ac
```

Now redirect only ld to newfile and ignore # started lines.

b) Now read the file from second occurrence of "#" to third occurrence of "". Thus we have following lines in above question:

```
 #ac
 bc
 acz
 c
 #hello
```

Now redirect only ld to newfile1 and ignore # started lines.

Comment: Eh? What do you want to happen to the lines `bc`, `acz` and `c`?

Comment: Hi bobbogo  '#' started lines are just to indicate the limit between. so these will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grep -v '^#' yourText > newfile
```

Comment: Dear Kent,  I need something like: first of all chose 2 consecutive "#" started lines and then read the lines between them.   For the next cycle again chose 2 consecutive "#" started lines and then read the lines between them.

Comment: can you modify your question with that information? also the input/output examples? from current question, my understanding is to ignore lines beginning with `#`  current: `If the line is started with "#" then ignore it and if it is not started with "#" then redirect the whole line in another file.`

Comment: Hi kent , I have modified the question please check

Comment: @user2069033 I read the new question, I cannot understand the b) part... :( why `ld` ??

Comment: hi kent, b) tells that as we selected lines between 1st and 2nd "#" at first selection similarly we will select lines between 2nd and 3rd "#" and so on.